# Predicting Building Fire Alarms

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, arima

I have Building fire-alarm data for around 6 months - Date and the no. of building fire alarms triggered for that Date. I have to forecast the no. of fire alarms that can trigger in future based on this past data.

I treated this a time series problem and used ARIMA for forecasting. I got the forecasted values but I am not convinced with the output and the strategy. I am thinking, whether it makes sense to do it? No. of fire alarms are not seasonal etc. They may depend of values from various other IoT sensors. Does it make sense to forecast no. of expected alarms based on past data? Should I try to get more (more features) data or my existing strategy is fine to go ahead with? Please suggest what makes most sense to do in this type of problem. How to frame this problem? What type of data should I collect and how should I go about solving this problem.

Please help me get some direction.

Regards,
Nandy.

Comment: Post a plot of your time series data. Also, plot the distribution of fire alarms, that is how long it takes for a fire alarm to go off after a previous one (reset the time each time).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that unlike other time series, incidences of fire alarms don't particularly follow a trend - or as you mentioned are not seasonal. e.g. if a toaster catches fire and sets off a fire alarm, that event is not in any way time-dependent. This seems to be more of a probability problem, i.e. what is the likelihood of an alarm going off in the future based on past occurrences?

If you wanted to go the time series route, then I highly recommend obtaining explanatory variables before doing so, namely pertaining to **the causes of an alarm going off.** For instance, buildings typically use more electricity in winter. If this starts a fire, e.g. due to a circuit breaker malfunctioning or some similar event, then this type of event would be time-dependent to an extent since electricity usage tends to be seasonal. However, other factors that are not based on time (e.g. smoking, candles, etc) would not be time-dependent. By separating into time-dependent and time-independent causes, you can incorporate such explanatory variables to better model this time series.

However, if you would like to model this as a **probability** (which would be my recommended approach), then I would recommend using the Poisson Distribution. In essence, you are trying to predict the probability of an event happening - this is not a forecast per se. The Poisson Distribution models the number of events in a given time period, given the mean number of occurrences. Let's take an example in R.

Over the past six months, 100 alarms went off, with an average of 2 per day. This would be modeled in R as follows:

```
#Parameters
x=0:100
lambda=2

#dpois = Poisson Distribution
probability = dpois(x, lambda)

#Histogram plot
plot(x, probability, type = "h", col="blue")
```

The generated probabilities would give a distribution as follows:

[image: poisson]

If this is not specifically a time series task, which I gather is not necessarily the case from your question, then this may be a better option for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Have you come across any project which has taken the time series route, the way you suggested? I think its make most sense to do it this way as it should solve a real world problem, at the end of the day.  Pls share any relevant resources/references if you know. Also, predicting the probability will be better for this kind of insufficient data using Poisson algo. But I have a feeling that this model will be far away from real world events affecting the alarms and thus, not appropriate.  Do you agree?

Comment: I don't have any particular resources, but if you go the time series route then you will need to have explanatory variables like I've described, e.g. weather, usage, etc. Also, it is my opinion that if you were to go this route - you will need data much longer than six months. If you are trying to extrapolate the effect of real world events on fire alarm triggers, then yes the Poisson Distribution would be insufficient.

Comment: Michael, thanks for your inputs. Also, what would be most appropriate algorithm/method to create a time series model with multiple explanatory variables, in your view.

Comment: You could use an Ordinary Least Squares that has been corrected for serial correlation, or another alternative could be an ARIMAX model (which is an ARIMA model but including explanatory variables).

Comment: Thank you Michael. You are awesome. let me try to read more about these algorithms.

Comment: Hello Michael, I have got many more features for this data now. Will it be possible for you also to take a look at it? What could be the top 3 usecases from this data according to you in addition to the one we already discussed, which will create the most business value. Shall I send the files to your email ID. Thanks.